# why all react component is in one file jsx?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm beginner in react and now I check a project that is like crisp and all off react component is in a one jsx file. I studing react and test some project but None of them is'nt like this.
this project dosn't have any ClientApp folder and subfolders.
this project is asp core and have signalR . file jsx use in a view action and run nice.
and how I can split componnent from main file jsx. I should create Appclient folder or not.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.